# woocommerce product variation title in table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to list my product variations in single product page in a table with their dimensions, everything is ok on dimension part but I cant get the variation name to be showed. Here is my code:

```html
<?php 

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ( $variations as $variable_array ){
    $variation = new WC_Product( $variable_array['variation_id'] );?>
    <tr>                                

        <td>
            <b>here I need the variation title</b>
        </td>                           
            <?php
                $magassag = $variation->height;
                ?>
                <?php if ($magassag != 0) {
                echo '<td class="cell_magas">' . $variation->height . ' cm' . '</td>'; }
                else{
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">#magassag-cim{display:none;}</style>
            <?php } ?>                      
            <?php
                $atmero = $variation->width;
                ?>
                <?php if ($atmero != 0) {
                echo '<td class="cell_szell">' . $variation->width . ' cm' . '</td>'; }
                else{
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">#szellesseg-cim{display:none;}</style>
            <?php } ?>      
            <?php
                $szellesseg = $variation->length;
                ?>
                <?php if ($szellesseg != 0) {
                echo '<td class="cell_latime">' . $variation->length . ' cm' . '</td>'; }
                else{
                ?>
                <style type="text/css">#szellesseg-cim{display:none;}</style>
            <?php } ?>          
        <td>
            <?php echo $variation->price;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`$variation->get_formatted_name()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.9/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php#L713) or [`$variation->get_title()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.9/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L556)

Also, I'm 95% sure you will want to use class methods instead of directly accessing the object properties will cause errors/warnings in WooCommerce 2.7. Plus it usually runs through a filter in case any plugins are targeting that value. (Ex: use `$variation->get_price()` instead of `$variation->price`)

Comment: Hi, but does not work with get_XXX. It is any direct access for variation name? Or the class method needed to be accessed from other variation query?

Comment: With  $variation->get_formatted_name() and $variation->get_title() I get the "variation #number of product name" but I need the title of product variation.

Comment: As Loic mentioned, there is no variation title. If the suggested methods don't do what you need, then please clarify. `get_XXX()` isn't always the correct method name, *and* it's a major change in WC2.7 that isn't necessarily backcompatible.

Comment: Another option would be `$variation->get_name();` as it will output the parent title followed by variation title i.e. _Red Shirt - Large_ instead of _Red Shirt - Large (variation_numer) Size: Large_ which is what I get when using `get_formatted_name()` :)